# using lamda to define member variable in class cpp

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a lambda to define a class member.  Pretty neat idea, but cannot get it to work...  Here is my example.  The "MyModel" object will get a parameter defined based on the definition of 2 other parameters.  Want to use a lambda to define the value of a member variable. Upon construction the first two parameters are passed.  This is convenient if the constructor may vary, but the value of lambda based parameter will always be based on the values of E and Nu.

```
class MyModel{
private:
  vector<double> _vE;
  vector<double> _vNu;
  // Use Brace initializer with lambda inside to define ...
  vector<double> _vC { [=](vector<double>&e, 
                            vector<double> &nu) {
    vector<double>c;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= e.size(); i++ ){
        c[i] = e[i] /  std::pow( 1 - _vNu[i] , 2);
    };  // end for
    return c;}};

public:
MyModel();
MyModel(vector<double> vE, vector<double> vNu): _vE(vE), _vNu(vNu)
{
 }
~MyModel(){}
};
```

I'll admit i think there is a larger problem with this idea. Still improving my usage of lambdas, so be kind.

Comment: It is not clear to me what it is you are asking, or even what your motivation is. Are you just trying to avoid using a constructor by using an immediately invoking lambda?

Comment: @Human-Compiler hopefully this helps.  Answer provided did work well for my case

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually call you lambda after you define it. Such pattern is done like the following:

```
int someVar = 2;
[...](int a) {/*labmda body*/} (someVar);
```

Note the `(someVar)` part, which is actually calling the newly defined lambda. In case your lambda doesn't take a parameter, just append a `()` after its definition.

So to fix your original code, just append the actual arguments to your new lambda definition like the following:

```
  class MyModel{
  private:
    vector<double> _vE;
    vector<double> _vNu;
    // Use Brace initializer with lambda inside to define ...
    vector<double> _vC { [=](vector<double>&e, vector<double> &nu)->vector<double>
    {
      vector<double>c;
      for ( int i = 1; i <= e.size(); i++ ){
          c[i] = e[i] /  std::pow( 1 - _vNu[i] , 2);
      };
      return c;
    }(_vE, _vNu)
    };
  };
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be aware that code-only answers generally are not received very well because it's rarely clear _why_ or _how_ it answers the question. Please consider editing your answer to explain the changes you made, and how it addresses the problem.

Comment: Editted. Hope it helps.